# Why does the util.inherits() method in Node.js uses Object.setPrototypeOf()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, prototype

I am new to Node.js, but already quite profound of JavaScript and its prototypal ecosystem. What I have generally heard is that `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, or assigning a new value to an object's `__proto__` property, is *bad*.

These `[[Prototype]]` mutations cause performance issues and lead to less optimized code. Now, when I try to get my mind, somehow, around this idea, I see that the `util.inherits()` method in Node.js uses `Object.setPrototypeOf()` to set the prototype of the first arg. The source can be found at [lib/util.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.6.1/lib/util.js).

**If `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is really that bad, what's the reason that Node.js uses it for configuring the prototype of a given object?**

And, would `Object.setPrototypeOf()` still be *that damaging* if I call it at the start of a given script, and be careful never to call it at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) is discouraged for the reasons you give, so is `util.inherits` -- for the same reasons. Quoted from the [documentation](https://doc.codingdict.com/nodejs-ref/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor):

> Usage of `util.inherits()` is discouraged. Please use the ES6 `class` and `extends` keywords to get language level inheritance support. Also note that the two styles are semantically incompatible.

This also suggests what you should be doing to avoid both `setPrototypeOf` and `util.inherits`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) adds this suggestion:

> if you are concerned about performance, you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using `Object.create()`.

Comment: Using `Object.create()` is impossible internally in `util.inherits()`, or least not *that useful* because the method `util.inherits()` has to get an *existing* constructor's prototype to inherit from another prototype. Right?

Comment: I wanted to ask one thing, which I even stated in the last part of my question. Would `Object.setPrototypeOf()` still be that damaging if I call it at the start of my script, and then *never* again in the middle of the script?

Comment: You can only be sure to avoid the performance impact when you set the prototype *at the time* of object creation, so for instance by using `Object.create`. The potential performance problem arises when you already have an object reference (with a certain prototype), and then that prototype has to be changed.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I think that's the reason why `util.inherits()` uses `Object.setPrototypeOf()`.

Comment: `util.inherits` does not create the object, but gets it as argument (`ctor.prototype`). This object was created (implicitly) earlier on, when the constructor was defined. So `util.inherits` *changes* that prototype, which implies the potential performance impact.